# python isnt returning any output back to php

Tags: python, php

I am trying to make a simple code to run python on user input but content_verification does not return anything back to the php file, email_verification works fine though. Been bashing my head on this for a while

content_verification.py

```
import language_tool_python
import re
import sys

def check_grammar(email_content):
    tool = language_tool_python.LanguageTool('en-US')
    matches = tool.check(email_content)
    return matches

def find_triggered_phrase(email_content):
    SUSPICIOUS_PHRASES = ['urgent', 'bank account', 'password', 'click here', 'login now']
    email_content = email_content.lower()

    for phrase in SUSPICIOUS_PHRASES:
        if phrase in email_content:
            return phrase

    return None

def is_suspicious_formats(email_content):
    SUSPICIOUS_FORMATS = [
        r'<a href="http',  # hyperlinks
        r'<!DOCTYPE html>',  # HTML doctype
        r'<html>',  # HTML tags
        r'<body>',  # HTML tags
        r'<script>',  # JavaScript tags
    ]

    for format in SUSPICIOUS_FORMATS:
        if re.search(format, email_content, re.IGNORECASE):
            return True

    return False

def main(email_content):
    grammar_errors = check_grammar(email_content)
    suspicious_phrases = find_triggered_phrase(email_content)
    suspicious_formats = is_suspicious_formats(email_content)

    result = ""

    if grammar_errors:
        result += "Grammar errors:\n"
        for error in grammar_errors:
            result += f"Message: {error.message}\n"
            result += f"Suggested corrections: {error.replacements}\n"

    if suspicious_phrases:
        result += "The input contains suspicious phrases:\n"
        for phrase in suspicious_phrases:
            print(f"- {phrase}\n")

    if suspicious_formats:
        result += "The input contains suspicious email formats.\n"

    if not grammar_errors and not suspicious_phrases and not suspicious_formats:
        result += "No issues found.\n"

    return result

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: python content_verification.py <email>")
else:
    email_content = sys.argv[1]
    result = verify_email(email_content)
    print(result)
```

php file

```
<?php
try {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $content = $_POST["content"];
        echo "Content: " . $content . "<br>";

        // Execute the Python script for content verification
        $content_command = 'timeout 2m python content_verification.py ' . escapeshellarg($content);
        $content_output = shell_exec($content_command);

        // Trim the output to remove any leading/trailing whitespace
        $content_message = trim($content_output);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exceptions
    $message = 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Thought that maybe it's because the code runs longer than usual so I tried adding timeout, didnt work
ran this code on terminal with my own input instead from php and it worked. it doesnt work when trying to get input from php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There's no `verify_email()` function in the python script. You need to rename `main` to `verify_email`.

Comment: You should capture `stderr` when you call `shell_exec()`, then you would have seen the error message. Add `2>&1` to the end of the command.

Comment: @Barmar it's working now tysm, man should've gone here ages ago, sorry, for the badly written question first time here